# Como verificar se uma transação foi iniciada no Zend

Tags: php, mysql, zend

Tenho um método onde é iniciado uma `BEGIN TRANSACTION` no Zend 1.12. Como ele é utilizado em muitos de lugares, ocorreu que um método que o chama já inicia uma `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, gerando assim uma `Exception`.

Quero verificar antes de iniciar se já existe uma transação criada. De que maneira posso fazer isso no Zend?

Answer (score 1):

O método `beginTransaction()` na classe `Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract` é o seguinte:

```
public function beginTransaction()
{
    $this->_connect();
    $q = $this->_profiler->queryStart('begin', Zend_Db_Profiler::TRANSACTION);
    $this->_beginTransaction();
    $this->_profiler->queryEnd($q);
    return $this;
}
```

Nesse método ele chama o método `_beginTransaction()`, que é abstrato e deve ser implementado pelos adapters do Zend. Logo, pelo que eu notei no código do Zend, não existe uma maneira de verificar se a transação já foi iniciada ou não. Você deve fazer esse controle na aplicação que usa o Zend.

O que dá pra fazer é habilitar o profiler (não recomendado) e buscá-lo por meio do método `getProfiler()`. A partir dele, pegar os profiles de cada query pelo método `getQueryProfiles()` e verificar se algum deles representa o início de uma transação.

Entretanto, como eu falei lá em cima, não é recomendado deixar o profiler habilitado 100% do tempo porque ele diminui a performance do programa. Você pode usá-lo para debugar a sua aplicação e implementar um controle manual de transações. :)

Comment: Muito esclarecedor, vou aguardar um tempo ainda pra ver se existem outras possibilidades, obrigado.